# unexpected directory layout when I build project

Tags: go

When I build project I get error like below, using Go 1.13.3 on Linux/AMD64.
I have tried a lot to build and run Go project but not able to build and run it.I have tried a lot of ways to run it but not able to do that

```
************  Building Go project: golangProject  ************
  with GOPATH: /home/username/Projects/Proj1:/home/username/Projects/golangProject
>> Running: /usr/local/go/bin/go install -v -gcflags "-N -l" ./...
unexpected directory layout:
    import path: _/home/username/Projects/golangProject/src/ip
    root: /home/username/Projects/golangProject/src
    dir: /home/username/Projects/golangProject/src/ip
    expand root: /home/username/Projects/golangProject
    expand dir: /home/username/Projects/golangProject/src/ip
    separator: /
   ^^^ Terminated, exit code: 1 ^^^
************  Build terminated.  ************


My go env is like that:

GO111MODULE=""
GOARCH="amd64"
GOBIN=""
GOCACHE="/home/username/.cache/go-build"
GOENV="/home/username/.config/go/env"
GOEXE=""
GOFLAGS=""
GOHOSTARCH="amd64"
GOHOSTOS="linux"
GONOPROXY=""
GONOSUMDB=""
GOOS="linux"
GOPATH="/home/username/Projects/Proj1"
GOPRIVATE=""
GOPROXY="https://proxy.golang.org,direct"
GOROOT="/home/username/go"
GOSUMDB="sum.golang.org"
GOTMPDIR=""
GOTOOLDIR="/home/username/go/pkg/tool/linux_amd64"
GCCGO="gccgo"
AR="ar"
CC="gcc"
CXX="g++"
CGO_ENABLED="1"
GOMOD=""
CGO_CFLAGS="-g -O2"
CGO_CPPFLAGS=""
CGO_CXXFLAGS="-g -O2"
CGO_FFLAGS="-g -O2"
CGO_LDFLAGS="-g -O2"
PKG_CONFIG="pkg-config"
GOGCCFLAGS="-fPIC -m64 -pthread -fmessage-length=0 -fdebug-prefix-map=/tmp/go build000300820=/tmp/go-build -gno-record-gcc-switches"
```

Comment: How are you trying to build your project? That output is not standard from Go. Are you using an IDE?

Comment: Actually i have a project from which is taken from the deployment server(not from repository like github) and i am trying to go lang project in ecliplse ide and gloand ide in both m facing same issue